# Understanding muscle tone

Tags: physiology

I am relatively new to Physiology, and I've just learnt about muscle tone.
I however find it difficult to understand the electrical changes that initiate (and/or accompany) muscle tone in **smooth** **muscles** .
To be specific, I know that action potentials(AP) cause muscle contraction (just like they cause nerve impulse propagation), and I also know that smooth muscle tone is a result of irregular contractions of the muscles at rest.
How then can these muscles contract when no AP is generated at rest?

PS: This question has been edited to achieve more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Action potentials usually maintain muscle tone in [*skeletal* muscles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle#Types), but muscle cells are affected by other influences that can affect their contraction and thus the tone of the muscle.

[*Smooth* muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_muscle) occurs in the walls of hollow organs, most notably the blood vessels and the [GI tract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrointestinal_tract), and in a few other places.  Contraction of smooth muscle is generally involuntary and can be stimulated by the APs from the [autonomic nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_nervous_system), but often for the slow maintenance of muscle tone contraction is controlled by [hormones, other external molecules, or external pressure.](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-540-38918-7_136)  The mechanisms that cause this contraction generally involve the phosphorylation of [myosin light chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosin_light_chain). [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_muscle#Phasic_or_tonic) [(2)](https://stke.sciencemag.org/content/1999/9/tw7)

Comment: If action potentials can at all maintain muscle tone, why is muscle tone spoken of as **passive** contraction? (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_tone). As much as I know, passive processes don't involve ionic changes seen in active ones (such as action potentials). If I am wrong about this can you point out the misconception?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: it has passed some time since my studies in muscle physiology.

Muscle have [stretch receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_spindle) to monitor the change in length. These are connected to the central nervous system, where information is properly processed and the response triggered. This response, as far as I know, propagates through action potential (AP) across neurons, which activate the muscle (transverse tubules, AP, Ca2+). In summary, muscle tone should be regulated by APs and I am not aware of another mechanism of muscle contraction in this case.

Do you have some references where they discuss another mechanism of non-AP muscle tone? I am very curious to know more.

/Emilio

Comment: My several days of research on the mechanism has turned out futile. But this is the statement which prompted my question: "...smooth muscles of some visceral organs maintain a state of partial  contraction  called  tonus  or  tone.  It is due  to the tonic contraction  of the muscle  that occurs without any action potential or  any stimulus...". It is from the text: essentials of Medical Physiology by K Sembulingam

Comment: @Chemo-Mike Pretty important to indicate you are talking about *smooth* muscle in your question if that's the case.